# How to retrieve child data from firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data  of name,regno that is saved in profile node and stored that data in list.

```
rootref= database.getReference("Student");

rootref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  try {

  for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

  //list.add(String.valueOf(ds.getValue()));

  // listKeys.add(ds.getKey());

  DatabaseReference rootrefprofile=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profile");


  rootrefprofile.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      Toast.makeText(Studentlist.this, "Exist profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Map<String ,Object> map=(Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
      String name=map.get("name").toString();
      String number=map.get("number").toString();
      String regno=map.get("regno").toString();
      list.add("Name:"+name+ "\nNumber:" +number+"\nRegno:"+regno);
    }

  @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  });


  listKeys.add(ds.getKey());
  // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The Request List of teachers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

listview.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Toast.makeText(Studentlist.this, e+" Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

I am unable to retrieve data from profile how can I retrieve data from profile.

Comment: can you please add the structure of your database? where `data` is stored and where is `Student`

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

```
rootref.child("profile").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    try {
      for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Toast.makeText(Studentlist.this, "Exist profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Map<String ,Object> map=(Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
        String name=map.get("name").toString();
        String number=map.get("number").toString();
        String regno=map.get("regno").toString();
        list.add("Name:"+name+ "\nNumber:" +number+"\nRegno:"+regno);

        listKeys.add(ds.getKey());
      }
      listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       Toast.makeText(Studentlist.this, e+" Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

do not add ValueEventListener for profile inside for loop, you can get it directly from the root

Comment: Good answer. But instead of the `String name=map.get("name").toString();`, I'd get rid of the `map` and use `ds.child("name").getValue(String.class)`.